# NormDist & Square Root calculation in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlcommand

Please check the below screenshot for data classification.

[image]

Just wondering is there any easy way to calculate NORMDIST, SQRT & PRODUCT using SQL commands just as like as I did below to calculate the AVG & VAR.

**Please note the below code I was using for another purpose and doesn't suit the screenshot values.**

`SELECT state, AVG([v2t] * 1.0) FROM portability WHERE state = 'Queensland' GROUP BY state`

`SELECT state, STDEV([v2t] * 1.0) FROM portability WHERE state = 'Queensland' GROUP BY state`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Oracle:
In Oracle/PLSQL, the sqrt function:

sqrt( n )

For Example
sqrt(9)     would return 3

sqrt(37)    would return 6.08276253029822

sqrt(5.617)     would return 2.37002109695251

For NormDist, try CUM_DIST.  The aggregate functions are documented in
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035

I do not believe Oracle has a function for product.